# Having trouble getting results from this query. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, subquery, northwind

Write a sub-query that returns the total number of orders placed by the customer with the
highest number of orders. Include the customerid and the number of orders placed.

```
USE Northwind
GO
SELECT CustomerID,
       COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS TotalOrders,
       SUM(OrderAmounts.DollarAmount) AS TotalDollarAmount
FROM [Orders]
Left Outer JOIN (SELECT OrderID, Sum(Quantity*SalePrice) AS DollarAmount 
      FROM OrderItems GROUP BY OrderID) AS OrderAmounts
  ON Orders.OrderID = OrderAmounts.OrderID
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY Count(Orders.OrderID) DESC
```

I get this response:
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'OrderItems'.

???

Comment: Have you checked that the `OrderItems` table exists? Why is it not in square braces like `[Orderitems]`?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the table `OrderItems` a member of the Northwind database or somewhere else?  You may have to fully qualify it with `[DatabaseName].dbo.[OrderItems]`

Comment: I changed it to Orders but the quantity*salesprice is holding it up now